# I want to find specific characters from txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Good morning, I want to find specific characters from txt file and create a new txt file. The file contain this lines:

```
Server: http://esv5.net:80/c/ 
MAC: 00:1a:79:17:52:ae 
Vence:February 28, 2022, 11:35 pm  
http://mag.abcdxyz.one/c
00:1a:79:d6:3f:2a;January 4, 2023, 3:17 pm 
00:1a:79:2e:e7:e1;July 30, 2022, 12:18 pm 
....
....
```

I want this output in same order:

```
http://esv5.net:80/c/ 
00:1a:79:17:52:ae 
http://mag.abcdxyz.one/c
00:1a:79:d6:3f:2a
00:1a:79:2e:e7:e1
```

My batch code is:

```
@echo off 
FIND "http://" "C:\Users\dom19\Downloads\file.txt"
FIND "00:1a:79" "C:\Users\dom19\Downloads\file.txt"
TYPE C:\Users\dom19\Downloads\file.txt > C:\Users\dom19\Downloads\Newfile.txt
pause
```

I add thiss command to save results bat not save:
`> C:\Users\dom19\Desktop\results.txt`
it just works like that

```
C:\Users\dom19\Desktop\script.bat >> "C:\Users\dom19\Desktop\file.txt"
```

Comment: Look at `for /?` from `cmd` specifically at `delims`

Comment: Please take a look at the output from `findstr /?` too.

Comment: here is a quick example `@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do @for %%a in (%%i) do @echo %%a | findstr "http 00:1a:79"`

Comment: thanks a lot, today all day to learn new code

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory & filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q71207091.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=: " %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%b"=="Server" ECHO %%c
 IF "%%b"=="MAC" ECHO %%c
 IF "%%b"=="http" ECHO %%b:%%c
 IF "%%b"=="00" ECHO %%c|FINDSTR /b "1a:79:" >NUL &IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 FOR /f "delims=;" %%e IN ("%%c") DO ECHO %%b:%%e
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Read each line, using both spaces and colons as delimiters, selecting the first token (to `%%b`) and the rest of the line (token `*`) to `%%c`.

For the lines `Server` and `MAC`, echo `%%c` only

for lines starting `http`, echo both `%%b` and `%%c`, re-inserting the colon.

for lines that start `00`, check whether the remainder of the line starts `1a:79:` and if it does, then retokenise the rest-of-line using `;` as a delimiter. Select the first token only (default), and `echo` the `00`, a colon and the part of the line that precedes the `;`.

I'm sorry, but I'm not clear on the requirement for the output file. The data will simply be `echo`ed to the screen. You've not provided any information on how to tell when the data you want is complete, so I can't provide you with code to terminate the batch.